# 'javax.faces.ViewState' value starts with '%' and not with '!'

Tags: jmeter, oracle-adf

While recording and ADF Application on JMeter, what should the regular expression extractor be when the javax.faces.ViewState recorded value starts with '%' and not with '!'.

I have been following the following link and it talks only about javax.faces.ViewState values that start with '!'

http://one-size-doesnt-fit-all.blogspot.in/2010/04/configuring-apache-jmeter-specifically.html

Answer (score 1):

One possible issue is that  the variable you are seeing is not decoded.

If this is the case, then you should see a %21 as a starting sequence that is the '!' encoding sequence.
In any other case, pls post the value found.

Comment: Yes, the values are starting with %21, so may I know what will the regular expression be in that case. The regular expression which I'm using otherwise is <input type="hidden" name="javax\.faces\.ViewState" value="!(.+?)">

Comment: I suggest to use some site to encode the text part of your regexp. 

Watch out to NOT encore the meta char part.

If you are OK with this answer, pls upvote.